# how to set a timeout for download in C#

Tags: c#, web-scraping, timeout

I am writing an application that downloads web contents.The problem is, when download starts, the whole app freezes until it download is completed. Is there a way to set a timeout which stops the process after sometime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want the whole program to freeze, then you can complete the download on a [`BackgroundWorker`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker?view=netframework-4.8), but if you simply want to run a process for a given amount of time and then stop it, you can use [`Process.WaitForExit`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.waitforexit?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Diagnostics_Process_WaitForExit_System_Int32_), and set the timeout to 2 minutes.

After 2 minutes, if it returns false, then you can use `Process.Kill` to terminate it.

```
Process process = Process.Start("myDownloadApp.exe");

//wait 2 minutes
if (!process.WaitForExit(120000))
{
    process.Kill();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Task.Factory.StartNew` allows you to run a function in a seperate thread. That means you can run your function in the background without affecting the main thread. Might be an option...

You could use it with `System.Timers.Timer` which allows you to run a process after a set time. You set that to 2 minutes and kill the process if it's still running. More info here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer?view=netframework-4.8